# Why this protected function create(Array $data) and not this protected function create(Request $data)?

Tags: laravel

I created a registration form with the use of laravel ui scaffolding.

What I did:

• Added some field besides the default ones

• Using the auth controller specifically RegisterController and change a part of the create function from this

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Into this:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'user_email' => $data['email'],
        'user_Type' => $data['user_Type'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'contact_number' => $data['contact_number'],
    ]);
}
```

But the result after submitting the form with a post method is this:

> ArgumentCountError
> Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::create(), 0 passed in /Users/idan/Documents/SweetSurrender/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 1 expected

Web.php

```
Route::get('/register', function() {
 return view('auth.register');
})->name('register');

Route::post('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'create']);
```

RegisterController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function index() {
        return view('auth.register');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:16'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'contact_number' => ['required', 'string', 'min:12', 'unique:users'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'user_email' => $data['email'],
            'user_Type' => $data['user_Type'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'contact_number' => $data['contact_number'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

I also tried using this in RegisterController.php

```
protected function create(Request $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'user_email' => $data->input('email'),
        'user_Type' => $data->input('user_Type'),
        'username' => $data->input('username'),
        'password' => Hash::make($data->input('password')),
        'contact_number' => $data->input('contact_number'),
    ]);
}
```

but it results to an error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_email' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ($2y$10$vr7UasRBCzx2URQxLSWneuvr4Hl1at.q7qDk8UK0Wc/INjeHeYH7y, 2020-12-22 07:15:41, 2020-12-22 07:15:41))

Comment: you don't route to the `create` method .. you have a `register` method that you route to and it calls `create`

Comment: you mean making a register method in the RegisterController and call the create method inside it?

Comment: you already have one, that `RegistersUsers` trait provides you all the methods needed for registration

Comment: The use of traits is still new to me and I only understand that include RegistersUsers via use RegistersUsers will allow the controller to do registration without requiring another code but I'm confused with how to implement it

Comment: `Auth::routes()` registers all these routes for you

Comment: thanks, I removed the routes that I personally added and I added the Auth::routes. Now the urls for scaffolding works but I'm getting this error when I submit the form in '/register' page

Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = speeps12@gmail.com)

Comment: you have to adjust the validation rules in that controller in the `validator` method

Comment: It still won't, I'm getting a new error from password confirm

Comment: because you need a password confirm field to use that validation rule, you need to spend time with the documentation and some of it will get clearer

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I learned a lot and has a clue on how I should approach laravel scaffolding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the same code:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'user_email' => $data['email'],
        'user_Type' => $data['user_Type'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'contact_number' => $data['contact_number'],
    ]);
}
```

and In the User model I included this:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'username',
    'user_email',
    'password',
    'contact_number',
];
```